# How to scroll to the index with SliverList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Scroll to index works with the ListView widget but not with the SliverList in customScrollView. Modified [this](https://github.com/quire-io/scroll-to-index/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) "Scroll to index" example by replacing ListView with SliverList. Additionally, tried similar questions from over the past, without any luck.

The desired outcome is to scroll to index by tapping the button.

[image]

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll_to_index/scroll_to_index.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scroll To Index Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Scroll To Index Demo'),
    );
  }
}
 
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
 
  final String title;
 
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
 
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const maxCount = 100;
  final random = math.Random();
  final scrollDirection = Axis.vertical;
 
  late AutoScrollController controller;
  late List<List<int>> randomList;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AutoScrollController(
        viewportBoundaryGetter: () =>
            Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
        axis: scrollDirection);
    randomList = List.generate(
        maxCount, (index) => <int>[index, (200 * random.nextDouble()).toInt()]);
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: ScrollController(),
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            title: Text("App bar"),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: _getRow(
                    randomList[index][0],
                    math.max(randomList[index][1].toDouble(), 50.0),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _scrollToIndex,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Text(counter.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
 
  int counter = -1;
  Future _scrollToIndex() async {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
 
      if (counter >= maxCount) counter = 0;
    });
 
    await controller.scrollToIndex(counter,
        preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.begin);
    controller.highlight(counter);
  }
 
  Widget _getRow(int index, double height) {
    return _wrapScrollTag(
      index: index,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightBlue, width: 4),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
        child: Text('index: $index, height: $height'),
      ),
    );
  }
 
  Widget _wrapScrollTag({required int index, required Widget child}) =>
      AutoScrollTag(
        key: ValueKey(index),
        controller: controller,
        index: index,
        child: child,
        highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Scrollable.ensureVisible (you have to give each list item a unique key, then use that to ensure the item is visible).

Comment: Yes, the outcome was that it almost works. Losing the key after the first scroll attempt. So far solution that works  has been  SliverToBoxAdapter, Column and ListView with Scrollable.ensureVisble

Answer (score 0):

You must consider what you are scrolling, you are scrolling your "CustomScrollView" therefore you need to assign the same controller from your AutoScrollTag to your CustomScrollView, then the scrollToIndex will work as intended.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    controller: controller,  /// Change this line
```